# Fetching Latest Record from MySQL for each individual

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like this

```
╔════╦════════╦═════════════╦═════════════════╗
║ PK ║  NAME  ║   DEGREE    ║ YEAR_OF_PASSING ║
╠════╬════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Shrey  ║ B.E.        ║            2004 ║
║  2 ║ Shrey  ║ High School ║            2000 ║
║  3 ║ Gaurav ║ B.E.        ║            2000 ║
║  4 ║ Gaurav ║ M.Sc.       ║            2002 ║
╚════╩════════╩═════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

How do I query to get a resultset of latest degree of each person as shown below?

```
╔════╦════════╦════════╦═════════════════╗
║ PK ║  NAME  ║ DEGREE ║ YEAR_OF_PASSING ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬═════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Shrey  ║ B.E.   ║            2004 ║
║  4 ║ Gaurav ║ M.Sc.  ║            2002 ║
╚════╩════════╩════════╩═════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Name, MAX(Year_Of_Passing) max_val
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY Name
        ) b ON  a.name = b.name AND
                a.Year_Of_Passing = b.max_val
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3579f/8)

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Name, MAX(Year_Of_Passing) max_val, MAX(PK) max_pk
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY Name
        ) b ON  a.name = b.name AND
                CASE WHEN b.max_val IS NULL
                     THEN a.pk = max_PK
                     ELSE a.Year_Of_Passing = b.max_val 
                  END
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3579f/5)

Comment: Many Thanks JW., there are cases with year_of_passing = null, in that case can I have the records with highest PK ?

Comment: Thanks JW. I have found this query `select
PK, Name, Degree,MAX(Year_Of_Passing) as Year_Of_Passing
from TableName group by Name order by PK;` giving exactly same output. Are they equivalent ?

Comment: @Shrey basically no. If you try to run that on any other servers, the query that query will generate an error.